# Jquery - Video JS error event GET/POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

First I'm using html5 video to embed my video, everything works fine when I handle error if video cannot played with this :

```
$('video source').last().on('error', function() {
alert('error play movie');
});
```

but on Video JS is not working at all,
The working on video JS is event on play like this :

```
var myPlayer = videojs('myvideo');
  myPlayer.on("play", function(){
alert('play movie');
 });
```

So, what event for error on video JS? Thanks anyway.
Im trying to put my GET function to error event VIDEO JS

```
$.get("<?= $host; ?>play.php?token=test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an handler on the [error event](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Eventserror) fired by the player like this:

```
var myPlayer = videojs('myvideo').on('error', function() {
    console.log('The following error occurred:', this.error());
});
```

I don't know if you need the details of the error but note that:

- the details of the error are not passed alongs with the event (so no param in the handler function)
- you must use `this.error()` to get error details as described in the [documentation](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Methodserror)